# Find all complex values for $a$ where there's no solution for the non homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Find all **complex** values for $a$ where there's no solution for the non homogeneous system

$$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {x + (1 - a)y + z = 1}  \\
   {2x - y + z = 3}  \\
   {3x - ay + (a - 1)z = 4}  \\
\end{array}} \right.$$

After moving to a matrix representation and reduction, I have:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & {1 - a} & 1 & | & 1  \\
   0 & {2a - 3} & { - 1} & | & 1  \\
   0 & 0 & {a - 1} & | & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$$

Now, I don't see an $a$ that answering this request, and I double-checked my reduction process.

**EDIT:**
followed by @DonAntonio suggestion:
defining $a= x + yi$

Developing the determinant by first column:

$$\begin{array}{l}
 \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {2a - 3} & { - 1}  \\
   0 & {a - 1}  \\
\end{array}} \right| = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {2(x + yi) - 3} & { - 1}  \\
   0 & {x + yi - 1}  \\
\end{array}} \right| = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {2x - 3 + 2yi} & { - 1}  \\
   0 & {x - 1 + yi}  \\
\end{array}} \right| =  \\ 
 (2x - 3 + 2yi) \cdot (x - 1 + yi) = 2{x^2} - 2x + 2xyi - 3x + 3 - 3yi + 2xyi - 2yi + 2{y^2}{i^2} \\ 
  = 2{x^2} - 5x - 5yi + 4xyi - 2{y^2} \\ 
 \end{array}$$

Comparing the result to $0$ we get:

$$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {2{x^2} - 5x - 2{y^2} = 0}  \\
   { - 5y + 4xy = 0}  \\
\end{array}} \right.$$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Do you know about a square matrix's determinant and its relation to solutions/no-solutions of a square non-homogeneous linear system?

Comment: I can recall that the determinant must be non-zero. Right?

Comment: Indeed (for the system **to have** one unique solution) @superstamp....so?

Comment: So, that's what left to do. calculating the determinant and checking when it's value is zero. By the way, this is also true for homogeneous system. right?

Comment: For **non** -homogenous square ones, @superstamp : they have a (*unique*, btw) solution iff the system's matrix has non-zero determinant.

Comment: Could you look at my edit please, @DonAntonio?

Comment: that's awfully complex ! You've gotten already an upper triangular matrix (I didn't check, I believe you...), so the determinant's simply the product of the main diagonal: $$1\cdot(2a-3)(a-1)=0\iff a=\frac23\;\;or\;\;a=1$$

Comment: @DonAntonio, Cheers. How could I miss that..

Comment: Just how we all do miss simple stuff now and then, @Superstamp...:)

Comment: I think there might be an error. Working out the determinant by hand, I obtain $(2a-3)(a-3)$, so that for there to be no solution $a = \frac{3}{2}$ or $a = 3$.

Comment: $Alijah Ahmed. I calculated the determinant of the matrix associated with the first expression and obtained the same result.

Comment: Thanks, Urgje, for vindicating my results. By the way, I need to clarify my comment: for there to be no unique solution $a = \frac{3}{2}$ or $a=3$.

Comment: Indeed , the coefficient matrix 

$[1 \ 1 \\ 0 \ 0 ]$

has determinant zero but that does not gaurantee the system of equations 

$ x_1 + x_2 = a$

$ 0x_1 + 0x_2 = b $

has no solution unless $b \ne 0$

The nature of solutions depends on b. To put it another way , if $b \ne 0$ then you are gauranteed no solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rref you get this

$ [1 \ 0 \ 0 \ \frac{3a - 4}{2a - 3} \\ \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ \frac{1}{2a - 3} \\ \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ \ \ \ \ \  0 \ \ ] $

So $$ 2a - 3 \ne 0 $$

$$ a \ne \frac{3}{2}$$

Now you still need to check a = 1 because if your calculations are correct , (I didn't check them) to get a 1 in the last row you have to divide by $a - 1$. If a = 1 you are dividing by 0

I checked a = 1 and it works. Putting a = 1 leads to the system

$[1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \\ 0 \ 1 \ 0 -1 \\ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ ]$

And this works by substituting a = 1 , x = 1 , y = -1 z = 0 in the OP.

UPDATE: I got it to this

$[1 \ (1-a) \  \ 1 \ 1 \\ 0 \ (2a - 3) \ \ -1 \ \ 1 \\ 0 \ \ \ 0 \ (a-3) \ \ 0 \ \ ] $

So even if a = 3 it will not produce 'no solution' because of 0 in last entry of row 3 , we would then have 0/0 which leads to a system with a row of 0's

I invite you to check a = 3 in the OP.

Comment: I got rid of the WA links because they looked 'bulky' and am now also doing the ref by hand thanks to a comment by Alijah Ahmed.